# Modal no recupera los datos correctos al editar un registro

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap

Estoy comenzando con Laravel (de hecho es la versión 8) y me he trabado en algo. Resulta que estoy pasando en una vista a un controlador, dicha vista es un "Modal" en donde se podrá editar la información de un "Cliente". Hasta cierto punto funciona, ya que al momento de inspeccionar elemento y ver si es que en la ruta me pasa el ID, sí lo hace, pero al momento de visualizar el Modal con la info que yo quiero, me bota otra data. Dejo el código abajo:

Ruta

```
Route::get('clientes/{cliente}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\ClientController::class, 'edit'])->name('clientes.edit');
```

Controlador

```
public function edit(Cliente $cliente){
  return view('clientes.edit', compact('cliente'));
}
```

Enlace al Modal

```
<a href="{{route('clientes.edit', $cliente)}}" class="btn btn-icon btn-2 btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit">
  <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="ni ni-bullet-list-67"></i></span>                                            
</a>
```

Formulario que está en modal(Vista)

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Nombre del cliente</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombCliente" class="form-control form-control-alternative" value="{{$cliente->nombCliente}}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Telefono o Celular</label>
            <input type="text" name="celCliente" class="form-control form-control-alternative" value="{{$cliente->celCliente}}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Direccion</label>
            <input type="text" name="dirCliente" class="form-control form-control-alternative" value="{{$cliente->dirCliente}}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">Referencia</label>
            <input type="text" name="refCliente" class="form-control form-control-alternative" value="{{$cliente->refCliente}}" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Actualizar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger  ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese botón y el modal están dentro de un foreach, cierto? Revisa que cada modal tenga un id único y que cada botón llame al modal correspondiente

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, Si estan dentro de un foreach pero esa directiva esta al inicio de la tabla, y no no tienen un ID identificativo pense que solo bastaba con la url pero al parecer no es asi por que por ejemplo, al boton de eliminar no le he dado un valor identificativo solo la ruta

Comment: Si utilizas el `find` pasa lo mismo?

Comment: Me refiero al html. En el botón se ve `data-target="#modal-edit">`, por lo que pensé que los modales tendrían algo así `id="modal-edit"`

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder a los dos, y disculpen si me demore he tenido una semana agitada. Juan Rivera use find y sigue lo mis. porloscerros por supuesto ambos tienen un modal identifcativo. quiero añadir algo mas resulta que hace un momento he intentado acceder a mi proyecto y me bota este error "Undefined variable: cliente (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\mammyaccesorios\resources\views\clientes\edit.blade.php)" en esa vista yo llamo a esta variable "{{$cliente->refCliente}}" y ese error me dice que no esta definica nose porque!! espero me puedan ayudar